# matlab batch processing on multiple hosts - what scheduler software is best suited?

Tags: matlab, scheduler

I was wondering what job scheduler is working best with matlab. I've looked into [slurm](https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/slurm/) and [gridengine](http://gridengine.org/) and don't see any striking differences that might matter for me. Are there any pros / cons I should be aware of? Maybe a different scheduler is even better suited for matlab jobs? I'd be happy to hear from you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use [Parallel Computing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/parallel-computing/) together with [MATLAB Distributed Computing Server](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/distriben/) to do this.

Parallel Computing Toolbox has built-in integration support for LSF, Torque, PBSPro, HPCServer; there's also a "generic" integration that allows you to work with Sun Grid Engine among others (sorry, I'm not quite sure which versions are which these days - maybe gridengine is the same thing). MDCS also ships with a built-in scheduler that you can use if you don't have one of the others. There's more details about supported schedulers [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/distriben/supported/sched/).

To do things this way, you need one PCT licence to submit jobs to the cluster, and as many MDCS licences as you want MATLAB workers to run concurrently. MDCS licences are significantly cheaper than ordinary MATLAB licences, and they use "[dynamic licencing](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/distriben/supported/sched/license_management.html)" which means essentially that your licence entitlements are transmitted from the submitting machine to the cluster. So, if you have, say, Image Processing on your machine, you can use it on the cluster without having to purchase additional licences.